# How to handle weekdays in a NN?

Tags: neural-network, keras, time-series

I want to test if using additional information of weekdays would improve my NN. Therefore, I just converted the weekdays numerically such as

```
Monday -> 0
Tuesday -> 1
...
Sunday -> 6
```

but my NN fails totally with that alongside to other 16 variables. Without it's ok. Now I wonder if I maybe have too few data or if the conversion does not make sense at all but I guess I do not need something like `one-hot-encoder`, or do I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is a cyclical feature, i.e. a feature which takes values which repeat cyclically in time. With that trivial encoding, for any algorithm, Sunday will be one day from Saturday, but 6 from Monday. It should be one day, also.

The proper way to handle cyclic features is to encode them with a sine and a cosine variable. So instead of a feature `weekday`, you should have `weekday_sin` and `weekday_cos`, which are calculated as:

```py
data['weekday_sin'] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * data['weekday']/7)
data['weekday_cos'] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * data['weekday']/7)
```

Although I can't assure you that this will work in your case, it is definitely a conceptual error you're dealing with.

For more in-depth explanation with some plots which make it a lot easier to understand, you can read this: https://www.kaggle.com/avanwyk/encoding-cyclical-features-for-deep-learning

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the very interesting advice! I haven't seen it like that. I also wonder that a NN will treat "higher" values as "more important". Is that really the case? I just thought for a NN all values would be arbitrary equal :)

Comment: NN will learn to treat something as "higher" since your input is used as a factor during backpropagation. At somepoint during backpropagation you will do <partial_gradient>*<input>...when your input = 1 it will give you a smaller value than input = 2 thus "learning" to treat 2 as higher as 1.

Comment: Additionally: cyclical features don't really work or rather work as good as non cyclical features when you train something tree based. This is because even though you achieve cyclical behaviour in your data the trees will split the cyclical feature into "greater/smaller than" anyway

Comment: +1, but you should divide by 7 instead of 6; as written, Sunday and Monday get the same embeddings.

Comment: Thanks @BenReiniger, just corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

If you create new features like

```
Monday -> 0
Tuesday -> 1
...
Sunday -> 6
```

your network will learn there is a some importance in Tuesday than Monday and Wednesday than Tuesday like wise. if there is no any special importance in each day,you need to treat it equally.You should use one hot encoding for better learning